# Raising `StopIteration` in loop body

Tags: python, loops

I had always thought that a an exhausted iterator raises `StopIteration`, and a loop catches that. This seems to align with what's said in https://bugs.python.org/issue31156. Now, running any of

```
a=[1,3]
itr = iter(a)
while True:
    next(itr)
    next(itr)
    next(itr)

a=[1,3]
itr = iter(a)
for itr1 in itr:
    next(itr)
    next(itr)
    next(itr)
```

crashes. This seems not to align with what's said in the above link:

> A StopIteration exception raised in the body of a while loop will terminate (and is caught by) the while-loop, thus leading to graceful termination.

Has the behaviour changed?

Comment: You haven't defined `itr`.

Comment: @kindall Thanks, changed.

Comment: A `for` loop catches `StopIteration` - but only during its internal call to `next()`.  `StopIteration` has no meaning whatsoever in a `while` loop.

Comment: That bug report itself was a bug. The submitter misinterpreted what they were doing, and requested documentation of a behavior that does not exist.

Comment: @chepner I see, that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop like

```
for x in y:
    <body>
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
itr = iter(y)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    <body>
```

(I say "roughly", because no name like `itr` is exposed to the body of the loop, I'm not handling the `else` clause of a `for` loop, etc.)

Notice that `StopIteration` is *only* caught when raised by the implicit call to `next` used to set the value of `x`, not if raised by something in the body of the loop.

Also note the last comment in the (now closed) issue from the reporter:

> Sorry, that was my misinterpretation of what happened.
> I had been stumbling over an old program I had written, but
> apparently it works because the while-loop is inside
> a generator function, and the StopIteration is simply
> passed on.